# How to determine revision of previous successful Bamboo deployment

Tags: deployment, bamboo

I use Bamboo CI to manage my git repo for Salesforce development. It runs my tests after each commit and if successful, then deploys to an org. This all works wonderfully except for when I've deleted files, because Salesforce needs a special xml built-up in order to remove them from the org. So I have added a step to my build process that will diff the repo (from previous successful build to HEAD), extract a list of any files which have been removed from git since the last build, and parse that information info into the appropriate xml format.

**The Question:** What I need now is a way to set up the *deployment* job such that it will be able to tell me the revision number of the previous successful deployment. Is there a way to have a script task set a value on a Bamboo global variable? If so, maybe I could just have a task which runs at the end of deployment record the current revision number and have it available to the next job?

**Note:** The *deployments* only run after *builds* are stable, meaning that there might be many commits (and builds) between last run and current run. Bamboo does provide a system variable for current revision number (`$Bamboo.planRepository.revision`) but the analogous system variable for previous revision number (`$Bamboo.planRepository.previousRevision`) is available in *build* environments only, with no such luck for *deployment* environments.

Comment: Bumping this topic; haven't given up hope yet...

Comment: `bamboo.planRepository.previousRevision` even not always available *build* envinronments. Example, for a brand-new branch build plan, it throws me `bad substitution error`.